# WaitForNextUpdate of renderHook of react-testing-library timeout

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm testing a custom hook with `react-testing-library` which basically does this:

```
function useHook() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  
  const fetch = async () => {
    const response = await httpCall();
    if (instanceof response !== Error) {
      setState("GOOD")
    } else {
      setState("BAD")
    }
  }
  
  return { state, fetch }
}
```

and my test file is something like this:

```
it("test", async () => {
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHooks(() => useHook())

  await result.current.fetch();
  expect(result.current.state).toBe(undefined)

  await waitForNextUpdate();
  expect(result.current.state).toBe("GOOD") //or at least "BAD"
})
```

I wrote this because I called the async function `fetch()` that should trigger the setState, I assert that no rerender has been occurred yet, and then I `waitForNextUpdate()` in order to wait this rerender and I assert that the `state` returned by the hooks has now a value `"GOOD"` or `"BAD"`.

My problem is that my test gives me an error: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms ...`, and this error occurred when the test waits for the `waitForNextUpdate()`.

I don't know what's wrong with my test. I'm sure (because i tested it) that the hook is working properly, the http call has been made. I know that checking values inside the test but also because the hook is working properly inside the application.
I don't understand why it seems that the update of the state never occures.

I'm the first one of my team who is testing with this tool so i'm quite lost.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have small mistake in if statment of the hook, so let's correct that and also add import of httpCall function for example sake

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { httpCall } from './httpCall'

export function useHook() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<string>()

  const fetch = async () => {
    const response = await httpCall()
    if (response instanceof Error) {
      setState('GOOD')
    } else {
      setState('BAD')
    }
  }

  return { state, fetch }
}
```

now we can have two test cases, based on mocking httpCall results. Note that rerender is used instead of waitForNextUpdate

```js
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { httpCall } from './httpCall'
import { useHook } from './useHook'

jest.mock('./httpCall', () => ({
  httpCall: jest.fn()
}))

describe('useHook', () => {
  it('should return error', async () => {
    // httpCall was mocked above, so we can replace it's implementation
    httpCall.mockImplementation(() => new Error('error'))
    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useHook())

    await result.current.fetch()
    rerender()

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(result.current.state).toBe('BAD')
    })
  })

  it('should return response', async () => {
    httpCall.mockImplementation(() => ({
      ok: true
    }))

    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useHook())

    await result.current.fetch()
    rerender()

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(result.current.state).toBe('GOOD')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `await` when calling the function under test of your hook.

It should instead be wrapped in `act()`, though as specified in the [documentation about async testing](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#async) it can be omitted when `await waitForNextUpdate()` is called.

The test passes with this change :

```
it('test', async () => {
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useHook());

  act(() => {
    result.current.fetch();
  });
  expect(result.current.state).toBe(undefined);

  await waitForNextUpdate();
  expect(result.current.state).toBe('GOOD'); //or at least "BAD"
});
```

Comment: Your answer is missing import statements, which are super important here, because there are several different react testing libraries that have a `renderHook` function. However, not all of those `renderHook` versions return the `waitForNextUpdate` function.